# How to identify the edges between a set of communities

Tags: graphs-and-networks, code-request

Given:

```
CommunityGraphPlot[
  ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "DolphinSocialNetwork"}]]
```

I like to identify:

1. The edges between each pair of communities;
2. In the context of a weighted network, find out the weights associated with the edges in (1); and
3. Combining all the communities in a single weighted adjacency matrix in which the edge weights between the communities are set to zero.

**UPDATE:**
Please see the example weighted graph to be used:

```
ClearAll[vn, select, mat, wam, wag, comm];
SeedRandom[2];
vn = Table[Subscript[v, i], {i, 20}];
select[matrix_, lB_, uB_] := 
   matrix*Map[Boole[lB <= # <= uB] &, matrix,{-1}];
mat = RandomReal[{}, {20, 20}];
wam = select[mat, .2, .3] /. {0.->\Infinity]};
wag = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[vn, wam];
comm = CommunityGraphPlot[wag, VertexLabels->"Name"]
```

Comment: can you post an example of a weighted network?

Comment: @kglr: Yes, of course. Please see the update of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dsn = ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "DolphinSocialNetwork"}];
```

**1. The edges between each pair of communities:**

```
ClearAll[cToCedges, edgesBetweenCommunities]
cToCedges = Module[{vToC = Association[
   Join @@ MapIndexed[Thread[# -> #2[[1]]] &]@ FindGraphCommunities[#]]},
    KeySort@GroupBy[EdgeList@#, Sort[vToC /@ VertexList[{#}]] &]] &;

edgesBetweenCommunities = KeySelect[Unequal @@ # &]@*cToCedges;

cToCedges @ dsn
```

[image]

```
edgesBetweenCommunities @ dsn
```

[image]

```
CommunityGraphPlot[HighlightGraph[dsn, edgesBetweenCommunities[dsn][{1, 3}], 
  GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"], CommunityLabels -> Range[4]]
```

[image]

**2. The weights associated with the edges**

```
dsn2 = SetProperty[dsn, EdgeWeight -> RandomInteger[5, EdgeCount[dsn]]];

edgesBetweenCommunities @ dsn2
```

[image]

```
CommunityGraphPlot[HighlightGraph[dsn2, edgesBetweenCommunities[dsn2][{1, 3}], 
  GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"], CommunityLabels -> Range[4]]
```

[image]

```
KeyValueMap[# -> (Map[# ->  PropertyValue[{dsn2, #}, EdgeWeight] &]@#2) &] @
 edgesBetweenCommunities[dsn2]
```

[image]

Using `wag` from OP:

```
MapAt[Highlighted, cToCedges @ wag, {Key[{2, 3}]}]
```

[image]

```
KeyValueMap[# -> (Map[# -> PropertyValue[{wag, #}, EdgeWeight] &]@#2) &]@
 edgesBetweenCommunities[wag]
```

[image]

```
CommunityGraphPlot[HighlightGraph[wag, edgesBetweenCommunities[wag][{2, 3}], 
  GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"], VertexLabels -> "Name", 
 CommunityLabels -> Range[Length @ FindGraphCommunities @ wag]]
```

[image]

**3.  Set the edge weights between the communities to zero**

This can be done in several ways:

```
betweenEdges = Flatten[Values @ edgesBetweenCommunities @ wag];
```

**i.** Get the positions of vertices connecting different communities and set the values corresponding to those indices to `0` using `MapAt`:

```
positions = Flatten /@ List @@@ (betweenEdges /. PositionIndex[vn]);

wam1 = WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[wag];

MatrixForm @ MapAt[Highlighted, Round[#, .1] &@ wam1, positions]
```

[image]

```
wam2 = MapAt[0 &, wam1, positions];

MatrixForm @ MapAt[Highlighted, Round[#, .1] &@wam2, positions]
```

[image]

**ii.** Use `SetProperty` to set the edge weights to `0` for edges in the list `betweenEdges`:

```
wam3 = WeightedAdjacencyMatrix @
   Fold[SetProperty[{#, #2}, EdgeWeight -> 0] &, wag, betweenEdges];

wam2 == wam3
```

> True

**Note:** If the goal is to get the edge list `betweenEdges` (that is, if we are not interested in edges connecting particular community pairs), it can be done more directly:

```
betweenEdges2 = EdgeList[GraphDifference[wag, 
    GraphUnion @@ (Subgraph[wag, #] & /@ FindGraphCommunities[wag])]];


Sort @ betweenEdges2 == Sort @ betweenEdges
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Comment: Your answers are not only very clear answers but also valuable material for a teaching tutorial. I learned a lot from your earlier posts. Thank you.

Comment: @TugrulTemel, thank you for the kind words and the accept.

Comment: Above, we have `wam3 = WeightedAdjacencyMatrix @
   Fold[SetProperty[{#, #2}, EdgeWeight -> 0] &, wag, betweenEdges];` which sets `EdgeWeights` to 0. I wanted to make edgeweights as a function so that I can adjust them at will and used  `-0.4*PropertyValue[wag, EdgeWeight]` in  `wam3 = WeightedAdjacencyMatrix @
   Fold[SetProperty[{#, #2}, EdgeWeight -> -0.4*PropertyValue[wag, EdgeWeight]] &, wag, betweenEdges]`. It did not work. Is this because I multiply a list of edgeweights with a constant?

Comment: @TugrulTemel, does `wam3 = WeightedAdjacencyMatrix @    Fold[SetProperty[{#, #2}, EdgeWeight -> -0.4*PropertyValue[{#,#2}, EdgeWeight]] &, wag, betweenEdges]` give what you need?

Comment: I tried it but since the matrix used is of a large dimension (1043, 1043), it takes a long time to get the results. I am still waiting for the result!!! I will also try it with a small matrix and let you know the result. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it works with a small graph of a (20,20) dimension. My matrix is large and it gets stuck, and I do not know what to do. Is there any trick to speed up (more efficient code) the calculation? Thank you very much for the `code`.

Comment: @TugrulTemel, try if `MapAt[- .4 #&, wam1, positions]` (where `positions = Flatten /@ List @@@ (betweenEdges /. PositionIndex[vn]);`) is any faster.

Comment: Yes, it is quite fast compared to what I have. At least, my computer generates a result without freezing. Thank you.